# Add Square proccesing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, square

I am trying to do https://developer.squareup.com/blog/android-in-app-payments-sdk-tutorial/

try too add comand to terminal

```
curl --request POST https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/v2/payments \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--data '{
    "idempotency_key": "129268cb-fd6e-4f96-b20e-a0a5a5f949b1",
    "amount_money": {
    "amount": 100,
    "currency": "USD"},
    "source_id": "cnon:CBASEFAEcrTTA3E_WAgmy_Bo7Ro"}
```

i modify it and now

```
curl --request POST https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/v2/payments --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" --header "Accept: application/json" --data '{ "idempotency_key": "ae7dabe6-2aec-42ff-b868-473cbeb8f847","amount_money": { "amount": 100,"currency": "USD"}, "source_id": "cnon:CBESEAHOhAS6638Hf9htX8WldY4"}'
```

and now it shows me errors

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
```

Comment: Try adding double quotes around the URL? In testing that request and replacing it with my own token under `ACCESS_TOKEN` and using the test nonce, it seemed to work.

Comment: I tried your modified curl command and it run successfully

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with my terminal i gess.
https://reqbin.com/curl - i have tried this service and now it working.